How to add customer Attribute inside custom tab section insted of "Account Information" in magento 2 customer attribute
I have created setup patch data using the attribute please check the below code and block using add custom tab
<?php
namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class AddCustomerAttributes implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        // Add global_customer_price attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'global_customer_price', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Global Customer Price',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 999,
        ]);

        // Add global_customer_special_price attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'global_customer_special_price', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Global Customer Special Price',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
        ]);

        // Add attributes to forms
        $attributes = ['global_customer_price', 'global_customer_special_price'];
        foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode) {
            $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
            $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['customerpriceform_']);
            $attribute->save();
        }

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

And the following other file
<?php
namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\System\Store;

/**
 * Customer account form block
 */
class CustomerPrice extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Customer Price');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Customer Price');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab class getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function initForm()
    {
        if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('customerpriceform_');
        
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Customer Price')]);
        /*$fieldset->addField(
            'global_customer_price',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'global_customer_price',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'label' => __('Global Customer Price'),
                'title' => __('Global Customer Price'),
                'note' =>__('This price sets the price for all your products for this customer. Examples:
                        ±10.99 - increase/decrease current price by given value
                        ±15% - increase/decrease current price by given percent')
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'global_customer_special_price',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'global_customer_special_price',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'label' => __('Global Customer Special Price'),
                'title' => __('Global Customer Special Price'),
                'note' => __('This price sets the special price for all your products for this customer. Examples:
                        ±10.99 - increase/decrease special price by given value
                        ±15% - increase/decrease special price by given percent')
            ]
        );*/
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->canShowTab()) {
            $this->initForm();
            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}



Filters are not working
<container name="assign_products_container" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">170</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <htmlContent name="html_content">
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\AssignProducts</argument>
    </htmlContent>
</container>

AssignProducts.php
<?php

namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Tab\Productgrid;


class AssignProducts extends Template
{
    /**
     * Block template path
     */
    private const TEMPLATE = 'products/assign_products.phtml';

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var EncoderInterface
     */
    private $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface|null
     */
    private $blockGrid = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context          $context
     * @param Registry         $registry
     * @param EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array            $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->setTemplate(self::TEMPLATE);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the grid block instance.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {
        if ($this->blockGrid === null) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                Productgrid::class,
                'category.product.grid'
            );
        }

        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return the HTML of the grid block.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml(): string
    {
        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve assigned products in JSON format.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductsJson(): string
    {
        $entityId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addFieldToSelect(['product_id', 'position']);
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['eq' => $entityId]);

        $result = [];
        foreach ($productCollection->getData() as $product) {
            $result[$product['product_id']] = '';
        }

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($result ?: '{}');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the current item from the registry.
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('my_item');
    }
}

Productgrid.php
<?php

namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Tab;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Productgrid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context    $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data               $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory      $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry                $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager          $moduleManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Visibility|null                            $visibility
     * @param array                                      $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $backendHelper,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        CollectionFactory $productCollFactory,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Visibility $visibility = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productCollFactory = $productCollFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->visibility = $visibility ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Visibility::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * [_construct description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('bliss_grid_products');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 1]);
        } else {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 0]);
        }
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * [get store id]
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'special_price'  // Adding special_price attribute
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'customer_price'  // Adding customer_price attribute
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'customer_special_price'  // Adding customer_special_price attribute
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );

        // Joining additional attributes like price, status, visibility as per your original logic
        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
        }

        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
        } else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_products') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } else {
                if ($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'html_name' => 'products_id',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'type' => 'number',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'type_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Type'),
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sku',
            ]
        );
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-price',
            ]
        );

        // Add new columns for the additional fields
        $this->addColumn(
            'special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Special Price'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-special-price',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Price'),
                'type' => 'input',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Special Price'),
                'type' => 'input',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/index/edit', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedProducts());
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $model = $this->productCollFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        $grids = [];
        foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
            $grids[] = $value->getProductId();
        }
        $prodId = [];
        foreach ($grids as $obj) {
            $prodId[$obj] = ['position' => "0"];
        }
        return $prodId;
    }
}

Inside Template File
<?php
    $blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
    $gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?= $block->getGridHtml() ?>
<input type="hidden" name="bliss_products" data-form-part="customer_perprice" id="bliss_products" value=""  />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Bliss_PricePerCustomer/js/assign-products": {
                "selectedProducts":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductsJson() ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>

Grids.php
<?php
namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;

class Grids extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context       $context
     * @param Rawfactory    $resultRawFactory
     * @param LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Rawfactory $resultRawFactory,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        return $resultRaw->setContents(
            $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
                'Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Tab\Productgrid',
                'bliss.pricepercustomer.tab.productgrid'
            )->toHtml()
        );
    }
}

Js File
/**
 * Created by : RH
 */

/* global $, $H */

define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;
        /**
         * Show selected product when edit form in associated product grid
         */
        $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryProducts.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});


1. setup patch data
<?php
namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Exception;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute as AttributeResource;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

class AddCustomerAttributes implements DataPatchInterface
{
    const GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_PRICE             = 'global_customer_price';
    const GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_SPECIAL_PRICE     = 'global_customer_special_price';

    private $moduleDataSetup;
    private $customerSetup;
    private $attributeResource;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeResource $attributeResource,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetup = $customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $moduleDataSetup]);
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        try {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            // Add global_customer_price attribute
            $this->customerSetup->addAttribute(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, // entity type code
                self::GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_PRICE, 
                [
                    'label' => 'Global Customer Price',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'position' => 200,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'visible' => false,
                    'user_defined' => 0,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
                ]
            );
            // Add global_customer_special_price attribute
            $this->customerSetup->addAttribute(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, // entity type code
                self::GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_SPECIAL_PRICE, 
                [
                    'label' => 'Global Customer Special Price',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'position' => 200,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'visible' => false,
                    'user_defined' => 0,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
                ]
            );

            $attributes = [self::GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_PRICE, self::GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_SPECIAL_PRICE];
            
            foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode) {
                $this->customerSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                    CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, // entity type code
                    CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER, // attribute set ID
                    null, // attribute group ID
                    $attributeCode
                );
        
                // Get the newly created attribute's model
                $attribute = $this->customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);

                // Make attribute visible in Admin customer form
                $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);

                // Save modified attribute model using its resource model
                $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
        }

            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

2. Add view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml to your module with the following
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="custom_group">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Price</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="global_customer_price" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Global Customer Price</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <imports>
                    <link name="value">${ $.provider }:data.customer.global_customer_price</link>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <link name="value">${ $.provider }:data.customer.global_customer_price</link>
                </exports>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="global_customer_special_price" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Global Customer Special Price</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <imports>
                    <link name="value">${ $.provider }:data.customer.global_customer_special_price</link>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <link name="value">${ $.provider }:data.customer.global_customer_special_price</link>
                </exports>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

</form>

Result :

